# Excel - Creating a formula for grabbing a specified amount of data separated by commas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make a formula in column E that is able to produce what I have shown there based off of the other columns. Its complicated to explain but I tried to make the example in Excel as clear as possible for what I want the formula to grab. I appreciate any help!

[image: Excel Example]

I'll try to explain further, sorry. So I want a formula in E2,E3,E4, etc. that can produce what I have shown there in those cells. For example with apple, if there is two instances and the total is 4 for them, and the qty is 2 for each, then I want the formula to grab the qty amount of numbers from column D from left to right, then with the next apple I want it to be able to grab the next 2 in the sequence after the first 2 have been grabbed. My expected results for the formula are what you see in column E.

*To answer questions that Scott had in comments*:

1. Yes you can depend on rows with the same value in Column A being a group.
2. Yes to everything.

2a. I though columns B, C, and G might be useful or necessary in a formula for breaking down the contents, but they might not be needed for the formula if column A, D, and F are enough to get the contents in E.

2b. Yes the result in E is depending on the row before it. From first to last in the group based off of Column A. For example if its the first apple, it takes the first numbers from left to right, the amount of numbers it takes is based off of column F. So then the next apple has a qty 2 in F then it takes the next 2 numbers following the previous two that were allotted to the first apple in the group, and so on if there are more than 2 instances.

@Rajesh S I realize I should elaborate on what the instances means as there is a misunderstanding. Instances is just counting how many there are in each individual group from column A. So you are correct in saying that column B is not needed for the formula determining what is inputted into column E.

Column F, the QTY, is what is determining how many contents are being inputted into column E.

Comment: you are going to have to try and explain better.  The photo and your description does not give enough for us to understand what you want.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: D4 Banana57 means E4 should be Banana57 - 27?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat The "Banana57" is the unique name from the two identifiers combined, the - is a hyphen not a minus, no subtraction, just meant to dictate data after the hyphen is associated with that identifier. The reason its 27 is because the qty is 1, so it has that many of the numbers listed from left to right, so the first number from the left in that sequence is 27. Then the next qty is 3 hence why the next row is the next 3 numbers after 27. Then after that is qty 2, so its the next two numbers after the last 3.

Comment: Multiple instances of the same container (i.e. column d) seems like a bad idea, but to clarify for other people: D is a shared bin of widgets for all rows of that type; each row F removes `n` widgets from the bin. The OP's setup for D is an array, and each subsequent row of that type is meant to start at offset(0 + (sum of previous F)) of the same type)

Comment: What version of Excel?   Mac or Windows or other?

Comment: (1) Is it possible to have `Fig`…`Fig1 - 17, 42` followed by `Fig`…`Fig60 - 83, 95`? Or can we depend on rows with the same value in Column A being a group?  (2) If I understand correctly, the value in Cell E6 is determined entirely by the values in Cells D6 and F6 (and maybe A6; refer back to point #1) — ***and also*** the corresponding cells on Rows 4 and 5.  (2a) If Columns B, C and G aren’t relevant, don’t show them, or at least indicate that they aren’t a factor.  (2b) If the result on a row depends on the inputs on previous rows, say so explicitly.  (3) Please post sample data *as text.*

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I believe that I understand your question and have an answer. Please [edit] the question to clarify it and confirm my understanding.

Comment: @jboom91,, your INSTANCE & Results in Col E has no relation,, let me say why,, in B2 Instance is 2 and you are getting first two 100 & 124 then next in B3 instance is 2 and you get remaining two are 126 & 128 and this should continue,, now in B4 instance is 3 and you are getting only one in D4 is 27 ,, in B6 instance is 3 and U get only two values 38 & 17,,,, **there must be a common rule**,,, please [edit] you post & be clear and loud all abut the issue,,, and avoid VOTE to close the post. Also share formula in you have tried so far !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In E2 (dragged downwards) :

```
=A2&C2&" - "&LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(RIGHT(IFERROR(RIGHT(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&","),LEN(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&","))-FIND("|",IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&","))),IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",")),LEN(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&","))-FIND("|",IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&","))),IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",")),",","]",F2),FIND("]",SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(RIGHT(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&","),LEN(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&","))-FIND("|",IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&","))),IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",",",","|",IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&",")),",","]",F2))-1)
```

Idea : `a,b,c,d` > `a,b,c,d,` > `a,b|c,d,` > `c,d,` > `c,d]` > `c,d` > `AppleX - c,d`
| sum, offset & countif is used to 'track' previous count, and used to place `|` & `]` marker.

Visually :

[image: all step]

with formulas (dragged downwards) :

```
I2 :   =SUBSTITUTE(D2,LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)+1),"")&","
J2 :   =IF((COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(F2,-1*(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1),0,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))
K2 :   =IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(I2,",","|",J2),I2)
L2 :   =IFERROR(RIGHT(K2,LEN(K2)-FIND("|",K2)),K2)
M2 :   =SUBSTITUTE(L2,",","]",F2)
N2 :   =LEFT(M2,FIND("]",M2)-1)
```

Please share if it understandable/works/not.

Comment: Wow, you rock dude! Thank you so much! This worked perfectly, it functions exactly how I wanted it to!

Comment: glad it solves.. ( :